# Java Web Start. Step by step

Tags: java-web-start

I have a JAR-file and that's all (including jdk). How can I do a java web start application? What the first step and the next ones?.. (on a localhost)

Answer (score 0):

please find all information at this page:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/overview.html#jws

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE, like netbeans, it can create the JNLP for you.

For instance, see this [netbeans Web Start tutorial.](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jws.html)